# PHP > Download ZIP : Network Error

Tags: php

i have a big problem with my php code, i use a html form for get the 'filename', work perfectly, BUT my problem is : when i launch the download, all browser's download zip files, and get Network error, ex : 578ko / 600ko : Network Error.

```
<?php
$dir = "lol/"; // trailing slash is important
$file = $dir .$_POST['filename'] ;

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Pragma: public');
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

    readfile($file);

} else {
    echo "Le fichier $file n'existe pas.";
}
exit;
?>
```

Comment: try to increase the time limit

Comment: What are your Apache Timeout, KeepAlive, KeepAliveTimeout values? If the directives are not set the defaults may be biting you.

Comment: I just extended the values and nothing :/

Comment: @Teddy76db remove all the headers and add only these headers and then try and let me know.
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: 'attachment; filename="'. $basename($file).'"'')
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

Comment: SmileIT solve my problem, thanks too dude's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your web server timeout values and increase/define to higher value. Also turn off output buffering.

```
<?php
$dir = "lol/"; // trailing slash is important
$file = $dir .$_POST['filename'] ;
//Turn off output buffering
if (ob_get_level())
   ob_end_clean();

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Pragma: public');
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

    readfile($file);

} else {
    echo "Le fichier $file n'existe pas.";
}
exit;
?>
```

Comment: This solution worked also for my problem of "Invalid archive" after the download of .zip files. Probably the output buffer change some headers or info of the response messing up the archive structure. Rar files still works but warn about a "strange" header.

Answer (score 1):

You can try reading and sending chunks - it might help

```
<?php

    $dir = "lol/"; // trailing slash is important
    $file = $dir . $_POST['filename'] ;

    if( file_exists( $file ) ) {

        header('Pragma: public');
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-type: application/zip");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename( $file ) );
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize( $file ) );

        /*
            send the file in chunks rather than trying to read and send all at once
        */
        if( $fh = @fopen( $file, 'rb' ) ) {
            while( !@feof( $fh ) and ( connection_status()==0 ) ) {
                print( fread( $fh, 1024*8 ) );
                flush();
            }
            @fclose( $fh );
        }

    } else {
        echo "Le fichier $file n'existe pas.";
    }
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: just tested this and it works fine with a hardcoded path to the file on my system

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. For reference, I changed the buffer to 256Kb.